# Faster way to compare strings similarity in python for big inputs

Tags: python, string, string-comparison, similarity, sentence-similarity

I'm currently needing to compare 2679 lines with another file of 550.000 lines to grab the most similar to each of them from the 550k lines file. I've been trying through a few ways like using `diff_match_patch` and `SequenceMatcher`, using two `for` loops in order to compare the strings, but it's taking forever. I can use a smaller file with around 22.000 lines instead of 550.000 but it still delays a lot. How could I make it go faster? any ideas?

Below an example of code i'm using to compare and get results

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
      return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

ppl_list = [i for i in rows1 for j in rows2 if similar(i[0],j[0]) > 0.96]
```

`rows1` contains the lines of 2679 lines file and `rows2` 550.000 lines.

`i[0]` and `j[0]` are fullnames strings like `Nilo Eduardo Rodriguês Perpétuo de Oliveira` and  `Nilo Eduardo Rodrigues Perpetuo de Oliveira`. That similar statistic of `0.96` i defined empirically after comparing a few strings. That's the code that is taking forever.

Comment: How are you comparing similarity? Are you looking for a case-insensitive match, regex pattern, Levenshtein distance, etc.? A simple example of your data would also help.

Comment: @Woodford i've updated the question with a piece of code i'm using and some more infos. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the *sliding window concept* .

1. Take first 2679 line and compare
2. Then leave the first line and add the line 2680
3. Compare again and keep continue to leaving first line and adding new line.

Comment: i think i didn't understand, isn't it comparing every single line as well and gonna take lots of time?

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit your definition of *similar* to "identical except for capitalization, whitespace, punctuation, and diacritics" then you can pre-process your dictionary (your 550k lines) and use hashing to make searching them much faster.

```py
def condition_string(s):
    # convert to lower case
    # remove whitespace & punctuation
    # convert accented characters to unaccented equivalents
    return conditioned

# pre-process your dictionary
dictionary = {hash(condition_string(s)) for s in long_list_of_strings}

ppl_list = [s for s in potential_matches if hash(condition_string(s)) in dictionary]
```

This doesn't work at all if you need to identify non-exact matches like typos or misspellings. In that case your best bet is to find a faster similarity algorithm because you're probably stuck with the O(n²) loops.